# Angular 10 Swagger Codegen: Generic type ModuleWithProviders<T> requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen, angular10

I am generating https://editor.swagger.io/ Codegen proxies.
It is giving the following error in Angular 10. How can this be fixed?

> Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

```
export class ApiModule {
    public static forRoot(configurationFactory: () => Configuration): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ApiModule,
            providers: [ { provide: Configuration, useFactory: configurationFactory } ]
        };
    }

    constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: ApiModule,
                 @Optional() http: HttpClient) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error('ApiModule is already loaded. Import in your base AppModule only.');
        }
        if (!http) {
            throw new Error('You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule! \n' +
            'See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error tells you that, the `ModuleWithProviders` class has 1 generic paramter. so you sould use it like `ModuleWithProviders<T>` where T is a type.

**EDIT:**

The class is defined like this:

```
interface ModuleWithProviders<T> {
  ngModule: Type<T>
  providers?: Provider[]
}
```

.

```
export class ApiModule {
  public static forRoot(configurationFactory: () => Configuration) : ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule> {
    return {
        ngModule: ApiModule,
        providers: [ { provide: Configuration, useFactory: configurationFactory } ]
    };
}
```

**See Resource:**

https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers

Comment: But from proper practice, we should not modify the codes generated from Swagger Codegen, any other approach to this solution? Maybe additional properties in swagger-codegen-cli command?

Comment: @Henry I agree, you can specify custom templates for swagger to use. See my reply for a solution that we use in production

Answer (score 3):

`io.swagger.swagger-codegen` fully supports Angular 10 since version [2.4.17](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.4.17). In detail you can se the fix which was provided in this [pull request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/10464).

As [djf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961781/djf) mentioned use the parameter `--additional-properties ngVersion=10` when calling `generate` to tell `io.swagger.swagger-codegen` to use Angular 10.

Comment: FYI 3.x branch of CLI is completely broken https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/11094

Comment: Sucks that open api generator doesn't fix this. I would be up for switching to swagger codegen but all the windows users on my team struggle to use it. So not an option.

Answer (score 2):

We stumbled over the same issue. Luckily you can provide custom *.mustache templates to the swagger-codegen-cli using the `-t` switch (see [the swagger doc](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#modifying-the-client-library-format)).

Our adapted api.module.mustache looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, SkipSelf, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
{{#useHttpClient}}import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';{{/useHttpClient}}
{{^useHttpClient}}import { Http } from '@angular/http';{{/useHttpClient}}

{{#apiInfo}}
{{#apis}}
import { {{classname}} } from './{{importPath}}';
{{/apis}}
{{/apiInfo}}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [],
  providers: [
    {{#apiInfo}}{{#apis}}{{classname}}{{#hasMore}},
    {{/hasMore}}{{/apis}}{{/apiInfo}} ]
})
export class ApiModule {
    public static forRoot(configurationFactory: () => Configuration): ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: ApiModule,
            providers: [ { provide: Configuration, useFactory: configurationFactory } ]
        };
    }

    constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: ApiModule,
                 @Optional() http: {{#useHttpClient}}HttpClient{{/useHttpClient}}{{^useHttpClient}}Http{{/useHttpClient}}) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error('ApiModule is already loaded. Import in your base AppModule only.');
        }
        if (!http) {
            throw new Error('You need to import the {{#useHttpClient}}HttpClientModule{{/useHttpClient}}{{^useHttpClient}}HttpModule{{/useHttpClient}} in your AppModule! \n' +
            'See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575');
        }
    }
}
```

The only change needed is to replace `ModuleWithProviders` by `ModuleWithProviders<ApiModule>`.
Afterwards the generated api.module.ts will work with Angular 10.

Comment: Not sure how this works, but will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @Henry our call looks like this: `java -jar swaggercodegen.jar generate -l typescript-angular -i api-spec.yaml  -o "${Temp}\src" --additional-properties ngVersion=10  -t "\Path\to\Templates\"`. The last parameter points Swagger to our custom template. The Directory contains a subdir 'angular' containing our modified module template file: `angular/api.module.mustache`. Make sure the directory and file names are correct. Otherwise Swagger will just ignore them. This is not documented well. I had to consult the Swagger source code to figure it out.

Comment: How exactly did you create the "api.module.mustache" file? I tried creating it but it ends up as ".txt" file extension

Comment: @Henry try renaming the file including the extension. That said, most text editors let you save a file with any given extension these days.

Comment: I tried with notepad++ but to no avail =/ 
any recommended text editors?

Comment: @djf wrong, the directory SHOULD NOT contain a subdir.

<templateDirectory>src/main/resources/codegen/typescript-angular</templateDirectory>

Where my "typescript-angular" directory contains my updated "api.module.mustache" file.